# How to update many-to-many relationship in prisma?

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I wanted to make a chat application that can do:

- user's can send/receive friend requests
- when user1 send friend request to user2 and if the user2

  - accepts the request : the user2 and user1's friends array will include each other
    and user1's sentFriendRequest array will remove the user2 detail
    and similarly the user2's receivedFriendRequest will remove the
    user1 detail
  - declines the request : everything like above just both users friends will include
    nothing

  The prisma schema :

  ```
  model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  username      String?   @unique
  password      String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]

  sentFriendRequests     Friend[] @relation("SentFriendRequests")
  receivedFriendRequests Friend[] @relation("ReceivedFriendRequests")

  friends Friend[]
  }



  model Friend {
  id     String  @id @default(cuid())
  User   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String?

  requester   User?   @relation("SentFriendRequests", fields: [requesterId], references: 
  [id])
  receiver    User?   @relation("ReceivedFriendRequests", fields: [receiverId], 
  references: [id])
  requesterId String?
  receiverId  String?

  @@unique([requesterId, receiverId])
  }
  ```

I used nextjs 13 API routes for this friend request accepting API:

```
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { FriendRequest } from "@/types/chatTypes";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { ZodError } from "zod";

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const data = await req.json();

  try {
    // valiadting user input
    const validatedData = FriendRequest.parse(data);
    const { receiverId, requesterId } = validatedData;

    // checking if user exists or not
    const requester = await db.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: requesterId },
    });
    const receiver = await db.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: receiverId },
    });

    if (!requester || !receiver) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "User not Found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    await db.$transaction([
      // Add each other to friends array
      db.user.update({
        where: { id: receiverId },
        data: { friends: { connect: { id: requesterId } } },
      }),
      db.user.update({
        where: { id: requesterId },
        data: { friends: { connect: { id: receiverId } } },
      }),
      // Remove from receivedFriendRequests and sentFriendRequests
      db.friend.delete({
        where: {
          requesterId_receiverId: {
            requesterId: requesterId,
            receiverId: receiverId,
          },
        },
      }),
    ]);

    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Friend Request Accepted Successfully" },
      { status: 201 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Handling Validation error using zod
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { message: error.flatten().fieldErrors },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: `Something bad happened, Try again : ${error}` },
      { status: 400 }
    );
  }
}
```

I know this code is wrong because id doesn't match either receiver nor requesterid and gives this error:

```
{
"message": "Something bad happened, Try again : PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
\nInvalid `prisma.user.update()` invocation:\n\n\nThe required connected records were 
not found. Expected 1 records to be connected after connect operation on one-to-many 
relation 'FriendToUser', found 0."
}
```

How can I solve this problem? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema, there is no direct array of friends on the user's table. Instead, it's represented as a one-to-many relation to the 'Friends' table. This means that you don't delete a friend record; it's 'removed' from the user's table by updating a status field in the 'Friends' table when a friend request is accepted or rejected.

Additionally, there's no need to manually check if the IDs exist in the API route because the database already handles that validation, and you can catch the error if it occurs, reducing unnecessary queries. Furthermore, you don't need to initiate a transaction manually in this case.

It's a good idea to add a status field to the 'Friends' table using an enum, ensuring consistency and providing predefined values for the different friendship statuses (e.g., PENDING, ACCEPTED, DECLINED). You will also need to send the status to the API route.

---

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  username      String?   @unique
  password      String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]

  sentFriendRequests     Friend[] @relation("SentFriendRequests", references: [id])
  receivedFriendRequests Friend[] @relation("ReceivedFriendRequests", references: [id])

  friends               Friend[] @relation("Friends", references: [id])
}

model Friend {
  id          String  @id @default(cuid())
  sender      User?   @relation("SentFriendRequests", fields: [senderId], references: [id])
  senderId    String?
  receiver    User?   @relation("ReceivedFriendRequests", fields: [receiverId], references: [id])
  receiverId  String?
  status      FriendRequestStatus @default(PENDING)// Define FriendRequestStatus enum & set to pending by default

  @@unique([senderId, receiverId])
}

enum FriendRequestStatus {
  PENDING
  ACCEPTED
  DECLINED
}
```

#### In next

```js
 export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const data = await req.json();

    // Should preform auth check

    const { receiverId, requesterId, status } = FriendRequest.parse(data);

    // Update the friend request status, works for accept & reject
    await prisma.friend.update({
      where: { receiverId, requesterId },
      data: { status },
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: `Friend request ${status === "ACCEPTED" ? "accepted" : "rejected" }.`}, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handling Validation error using zod
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: error.flatten().fieldErrors }, { status: 400 });
    }
    if (error instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      // https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/error-reference#p2025
      if (error.code === "P2025") {
        // User not found error
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "User not Found" },{ status: 404 });
      }
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "Unexpected error occurred" }, { status: 500 });
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Here are some example queries

#### Send a request

```js
await prisma.friend.create({
  data: { senderId: "YOUR_SENDER_ID", receiverId: "YOUR_RECIEVER_ID" } // don't need to set status here bc it defaults to pending in the DB
});
```

#### User's sent request

```js
const sentFriendRequests = await prisma.friend.findMany({
  where: {
    senderId: "YOUR_USER_ID", // Replace with the actual user's ID
    status: "PENDING", // Assuming you want to retrieve pending sent requests
  },
  select: {
    receiver: true, // This selects the receiver (the recipient of the request)
  },
});
```

#### User's pending request

```js
const pendingFriendRequests = await prisma.friend.findMany({
  where: {
    receiverId: "YOUR_USER_ID", // Replace with the actual user's ID
    status: "PENDING",
  },
});
```

#### User's friends

```js
const acceptedFriends = await prisma.friend.findMany({
  where: {
    senderId: "YOUR_USER_ID", // Replace with the actual user's ID
    status: "ACCEPTED",
  },
  select: {
    receiver: true, // This selects the receiver (your friend)
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, I will definitely try this out.

Comment: Yeah everything is working as expected Thanks again.